# Strange behavior of Oracle trigger when data inserted from a Java application

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, triggers, eclipselink

I have a table in Oracle with a Timestamp with Time Zone (TIMESTAMPTZ) column type.  I also have a trigger on this table to convert the incoming timestamp from the local time zone (EST) to GMT.    When I insert data to the table using SqlPlus/SQL Developer, the trigger works well and translates the time zone correctly.  But when I attempt to insert data from a Java application (using JPA/EclipseLink), the time is rounded to the nearest full second (losing the fractional component).   If I disable the trigger, the time is inserted correctly, except in the local time zone.

I know that I can work around the issue by performing the translation to GMT in my Java app.   But there are multiple ways data can be inserted into this table and will require changes to many apps, some Java and some SQL.   Hence it is more convenient for us to perform the translation in the Trigger.  Have anyone come across this before?   Any help in fixing the trigger will be greatly appreciated.

Sample records,

With trigger disabled from Java or inserted from SQL developer

```
Id      TS_COL                          TS_TZ_COL
101     21-FEB-16 13.10.10.223000000    21-FEB-16 13.10.10.223000000 AMERICA/NEW_YORK
```

Inserted with Trigger enabled

```
Id      TS_COL                          TS_TZ_COL
103     21-FEB-16 14.22.02.654000000    21-FEB-16 19.22.02.000000000 GMT
```

Here is small example to illustrate the issue.   I am using Oracle 12.1.0 and tried this on both instances running on Redhat Enterprise and Windows 10.   Any help will be useful.

Table and Trigger definition

```
 CREATE TABLE TZ_TEST (  myid  NUMBER (4,0) not null primary key, TS_COL TIMESTAMP (6), TS_TZ_COL TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE)


CREATE OR REPLACE 
TRIGGER TZ_TEST_TRIGGER 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON TZ_TEST 
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF (:NEW.TS_TZ_COL is not null)
   THEN
      :NEW.TS_TZ_COL := (from_tz(cast(:NEW.TS_TZ_COL as timestamp), 'America/New_York') at time zone 'GMT');
   END IF;
END;
```

JPA entity

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="TZ_TEST")
public class TzTest implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="myid")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="TS_COL")
    private Timestamp tsCol;

    @Column(name="TS_TZ_COL")
    private Timestamp tsTzCol;

    public TzTest() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Timestamp getTsCol() {
        return this.tsCol;
    }

    public void setTsCol(Timestamp tsCol) {
        this.tsCol = tsCol;
    }

    public Timestamp getTsTzCol() {
        return this.tsTzCol;
    }

    public void setTsTzCol(Timestamp tsTzCol) {
        this.tsTzCol = tsTzCol;
    }

}
```

Test code that inserts a record

```
@Test
public void test() throws ParseException {      
    Timestamp ts1 = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    TzTest tzTest1 = new TzTest();
    tzTest1.setId(103);
    tzTest1.setTsCol(ts1);
    tzTest1.setTsTzCol(ts1);

    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(tzTest1);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

}
```

Comment: This really smells like a data issue. I suggest that you modify your trigger to log the values the trigger receives using UTL_FILE. Then you can see what the trigger is seeing, and what it's producing. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks Bob.   That is what I initially suspected.   But value is there.  Here is what I get if the TZ conversion line commented out.   23-FEB-16 06.16.32.492000 AM AMERICA/NEW_YORK.   But the moment that line is added back it becomes 23-FEB-16 06.16.32.000000 AM GMT. It seems as though any function call from_tz or cast on the timestamp with time zone value coming in causing the truncation.

Comment: Instead of casting to "TIMESTAMP", try casting to "TIMESTAMP(6)". Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks Bob.  That didn't work.   Eventually we worked around this by translating the value for the Timestamp field (TS_COL) to GMT  as TS_TZ_COL in the trigger.    This was acceptable for us.